# errors.GrailsExceptionResolver StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: grails

I just upgraded my application from 2.3.5 to 2.4.4. I'm still using the resources plugin as I don't have time to make all the changes required for asset pipeline.

In my layout I have the following code which seems fine to me

```
<%@ page import="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link href="<g:resource dir="css" file="theme.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<g:resource dir="css" file="features.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But I keep getting the error: `errors.GrailsExceptionResolver StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on line `<link href="<g:resource dir="css" file="theme.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">`

The entire stacktrace is below

```
pages.GroovyPagesServlet FrameworkServlet 'gsp': initialization completed in 9 ms
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver StringIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app/login/auth
String index out of range: 6. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : bootstrap
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
C
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. `StringIndexOutOfBound` seems absurd for `<g:resource>` tag.

**Sample App**

I've created a sample app that demonstrates the issue https://github.com/Omnipresent/indexoutofbound